# how to concatenate contents with linebreaks in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, concatenation

I have three columns (col1, col2, col3) having string contents with line breaks inserted. I would like to concatenate col1,col2 and col3 with new column (DesiredCol) as shown below

[image]

Here is the dataset

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': ["ABC1"+"\n"+"ABC2"+"\n"+"ABC3", "BBC1"+"\n"+"BBC2"+"\n"+"BBC3"], 'col2': ["A"+"\n"+"B"+"\n"+"C", "A"+"\n"+"B"+"\n"+"C"],'col3': ["YES"+"\n"+"NO"+"\n"+"YES", "NO"+"\n"+"NO"+"\n"+"YES"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I tried using lambda function as below, however its not giving the desired column

```
cols=['col1','col2','col3']

df['DesiredCol'] = df[cols].apply(lambda row: ' '.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible solution (the key being to use the `zip` built-in function to join the respective elements, and then further `apply` methods on the dataframe to insert the desired newline characters specifically):

## A) Edit: Fastest Solution

> (Thanks to mozway.)
> For an understanding of what this code achieves, and how each operation changes the data step by step into the desired column output, see solution "B" below. However, for large dataframes, it is better to avoid the use of `applymap` and instead combine `map` and `zip` in a list comprehension as shown here.

```py
df['DesiredCol'] = ['\n\n'.join(map(' '.join, zip(*(y.splitlines() for y in x))))
                    for x in zip(*(df[c] for c in cols))]
```

## B) Original Solution

> Providing a breakdown of the dataframe operations. *Note: `applymap` is a simple way of applying a function to every element (or cell) of a dataframe and is shown here for illustration of the intermittent states of the dataframe, but usually there is a faster approach.

### Full code:

##### Computationally more efficient solution:

> However, solution "A" above will be faster and is recommended. Using the transpositions as shown here is not the most efficient approach.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df2 = df.T.apply(
    lambda x: list(
        map(" ".join, list(zip(*[y.split("\n") for y in x.values])))
    )
).T

cols = df2.columns
df['col4'] = df2[cols].astype(str).apply('\n'.join, axis=1)
```

##### Full code for solution as used in explained steps below:

```py
df2 = df.applymap(lambda s: s.split('\n'))

df3 = df2.T.apply(lambda x: list(zip(*x.values)))

df3 = df3.T.apply(lambda x: x.str.join(' '))

cols = df3.columns
df['col4'] = df3[cols].astype(str).apply('\n'.join, axis=1)
```

## Breakdown of df operations

#### 1) Use `applymap`* to delimit each cell in cols 1-3

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {
    "col1": [
        "ABC1" + "\n" + "ABC2" + "\n" + "ABC3",
        "BBC1" + "\n" + "BBC2" + "\n" + "BBC3",
    ],
    "col2": ["A" + "\n" + "B" + "\n" + "C", "A" + "\n" + "B" + "\n" + "C"],
    "col3": [
        "YES" + "\n" + "NO" + "\n" + "YES",
        "NO" + "\n" + "NO" + "\n" + "YES",
    ],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df2 = df.applymap(lambda s: s.split("\n"))
df2
```

[image: showing effect of first apply method delimiting by newline characters]

#### 2) Then, apply `zip` to respectively join the elements of the lists from the columns

```py
df3 = df2.T.apply(lambda x: list(zip(*x.values)))

df3 = df3.T.apply(lambda x: x.str.join(" "))
df3
```

[image: showing the now zipped elements from the three cols of orig df]

#### 3) And lastly join the zipped new multi-column-concatenated lists into newline character-delimited strings

```py
cols = df3.columns
df["col4"] = df3[cols].astype(str).apply("\n".join, axis=1)

df
```

which gives the final solution:

[image: Dataframe with zipped and joined by newline string concatenation]

Comment: Thanks John for your explanation, i knew there is split function, but was stuck on how to proceed further, your solution is what i was looking for .Thanks again

Comment: small update, as i needed two linebreak, nonetheless perfect solution! df["col4"] = df3[cols].astype(str).apply("\n\n".join, axis=1)

Answer (score 2):

Using a list comprehension with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
df['out'] = [list(map(' '.join, zip(*(y.splitlines() for y in x))))
             for x in zip(df['col1'], df['col2'], df['col3'])]

               col1     col2          col3                                  out
0  ABC1\nABC2\nABC3  A\nB\nC  YES\nNO\nYES  [ABC1 A YES, ABC2 B NO, ABC3 C YES]
1  BBC1\nBBC2\nBBC3  A\nB\nC   NO\nNO\nYES   [BBC1 A NO, BBC2 B NO, BBC3 C YES]
```

And for a double line break:

```
df['out'] = ['\n\n'.join(map(' '.join, zip(*(y.splitlines() for y in x))))
             for x in zip(df['col1'], df['col2'], df['col3'])]

               col1     col2          col3                                    out
0  ABC1\nABC2\nABC3  A\nB\nC  YES\nNO\nYES  ABC1 A YES\n\nABC2 B NO\n\nABC3 C YES
1  BBC1\nBBC2\nBBC3  A\nB\nC   NO\nNO\nYES   BBC1 A NO\n\nBBC2 B NO\n\nBBC3 C YES
```

###### generalization to an arbitrary number of columns

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
# for all columns
# cols = list(df)

df['DesiredCol'] = ['\n\n'.join(map(' '.join, zip(*(y.splitlines() for y in x))))
                    for x in zip(*(df[c] for c in cols))]
```

#### comparison of answers

###### difference in behavior

- John's and Mark's approaches use all columns, thus if you repeat the operation, the output is included. To avoid this behavior in the timing I added in all approaches a step to check for and remove the output column before running the code. I also added an alternative approach in my answer to handle an arbitrary number of columns.
- Pravash' approach uses the same string to `join` the strings chunks and the joined substrings, which I ignored for the timing considering it a valid output.

###### timings for a varying number of rows

John's code is likely slower due to the use of `applymap` and of pandas to perform the transposition operations (constructing the intermediate DataFrames is expensive). Mark's approach bottlenecks are the use of `explode` and `groupby`.

[image]

Comment: @Arun I added a comparison of the approaches to illustrate their difference in behavior, and a comparison of timings. NB. this is mostly for future readers, don't feel that you have to change your mind about the accepted answer ;)

Comment: quite impressive, really got knowledge sharing for readers as well

Comment: I agree this is a more elegant solution; I was merely providing one that worked quickly. Thanks for the analysis

Comment: I updated my answer to include a discouragement on the use of `applymap` and provide an additional unique solution, very similar to mozway's, which removes the use of `applymap` (but still includes transpositions), and therefore should show improved timing. Still, I highlight mozway's solution as being the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using below code -

I have used zip and split('\n') to create individual tuples for rows in cols.

```
df["DesiredCol"] = df.apply(lambda row: " ".join(value for col in zip(row["col1"].split("\n"), row["col2"].split("\n"), row["col3"].split("\n")) for value in col), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks Pravash, looks similar to what John has shared, but this code is really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another answer

```
o = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('\n').explode()).apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1)
df['new col'] = o.groupby(o.index).apply(lambda x: '\n'.join(x)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Brilliant solution! close to what i was looking for!